# php with framework of codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

```
function invitation_result()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    $qry = mysql_query("select * from sent_invitations where user_id='$user_id'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($qry) > 0) 
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
           $mobile_number = $row['mobile_number'];

           $qry1 = mysql_query("select mobile_number from users where mobile_number = '$mobile_number'");
           $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry1);
           $mobile_number = $row1['mobile_number'];
           $users[] = array('mobile_number' => $mobile_number );
           return $users;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is my coding.
In sent_invitation table there are 3 rows with user_id=11.
from there i m trying to get mobile_number of all three rows based on user_id.
the mobile_number of all 3 rows is different.
after geting mobile_number from sent_notification table.
i m comparing the mobile_number with mobile_number of users table.
i m seeing that 3 of them mobile_numbers are there in users table.
i m trying to show all of them.
bt problem is that my code id showing only one row and that is of last mobile number from 3

Comment: Use mysqli as mysql has been depreciated.

Comment: Tip: Also so you don't have to use `$this->load->database();` you can autoload it in config/autoload.php

Comment: And codeigniter has database features here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: how it possible single user in send_invitation table has three different mobile number

Comment: this is what i get the result when i run my 
{"status":"true","response":[{"mobile_number":"69"}]}

Comment: Look at where your return $users is located. Inside the while loop! So the loop runs once and you leave... Move it outside the while loop... for starters...

Comment: THNX alot @TimBrownlaw
Its working sir

Comment: You are welcome but take heed of everyones ( including mine ) advice and dont use mysql_xxxx use mysqli or pdo... Oh yeah we are using Codeigniter here so use the CI Query Builder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `while` loop where you are getting `mobile_number` in inner loop.

```
function invitation_result()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    $qry = $this->db->query("select * from sent_invitations where user_id='$user_id'");

    if ($qry->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        while ($qry->result_array() as $row)
        {
           $mobile_number = $row['mobile_number'];

           $qry1 = $this->db->query("select mobile_number from users where mobile_number = '$mobile_number'");
           if($qry1->num_rows() > 0){
           while($qry1->result_array() as $row1){
              $mobile_number = $row1['mobile_number'];
              $users[] = array('mobile_number' => $mobile_number );
           }
           return $users;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

You should use codeigniter database query instead of `mysql` custom query. because `mysql` is deprecated. You can use below code:

```
function invitation_result()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    $qry = mysqli_query("select * from sent_invitations where user_id='$user_id'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($qry) > 0) 
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
           $mobile_number = $row['mobile_number'];

           $qry1 = mysql_query("select mobile_number from users where mobile_number = '$mobile_number'");
           $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry1);
           $mobile_number = $row1['mobile_number'];
           $users[] = array('mobile_number' => $mobile_number );
           return $users;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Codeigniter You should follow the MVC pattern :

So the code in the controller should be :

```
public function invitation_result(){
     $userId = 0;
     if(($_GET['user_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['user_id']) && $_GET['user_id'] > 0){
      $userId = $_GET['user_id'];
     }
     $data = $this->User_model->getDataFromID($userId);
     return $data;
}
```

And the code for Model should be :

```
public function getDataFromID($userId){
    $arrReturn = array();
    if(($userId) && is_numeric($userId) && $userId > 0){
        $this->db->select('*');//You can put the required fields here like : name,mobile_number...
        $this->db->from('sent_invitations');
        $this->db->where("user_id",$user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if(!empty($result)){
            foreach($result as $key=>$value){
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('mobile_number');
                $this->db->where("mobile_number",$value['mobile_number']);
                $querySub = $this->db->get();
                $resultSub = $querySub->result_array();
                if(!empty($resultSub)){
                    array_push($arrReturn,$resultSub);
                }
            }
            return $arrReturn;
        }
    }else{
        return $arrReturn; 
    }
}
```

By the time I have written the Answer you would have solved the error ,but this answer will help future Users.

Answer (score 0):

first, can you simplified the query something like this ?

```
$sql = "select a.*, b.mobile_number as user_mobile_number
        from   sent_invitations a
        join   users            b on a.user_id = b.user_id";
```

or

```
$sql = "select a.*, b.mobile_number as user_mobile_number
        from   sent_invitations a
        join   users            b on a.mobile_number = b.mobile_number";
```

it's depend on how this two tables can be related.

Now you can see if the *sent_invitations.mobile_number* also found in *users.mobile_number* just in one query. If this returns multiple same rows, then put distinct keyword after SELECT

second, back to your code, i think you should move **return $users** out form while block

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    // your code
 }
 return $users;
```

good luck;

Answer (score 0):

```
function invitation_result()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    $qry = $this->db->query("select * from sent_invitations where user_id='$user_id'");
    $results = $qry->result();
    foreach ($results as $result) 
    {
        $mobile_number = $result->mobile_number;

        $qry1 = $this->db->query("select mobile_number from users where mobile_number = '$mobile_number'");
        $results1 = $qry1->result();
        foreach ($results1 as $result1) 
        {
            $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry1);
            $mobile_number = $result1->mobile_number;
            $users = array('mobile_number' => $mobile_number );
            return $users;
        }
    }
}
```