# showing null result whereas i only want desired result in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image]

The below is my coding.

In `sent_invitation` table there are 3 rows with `user_id=11`.
from there i m trying to get mobile_number of all three rows based on `user_id`.
the mobile_number of all 3 rows is different.
after geting `mobile_number` from `sent_invitation` table.
i m comparing the `mobile_number` with mobile_number of users table.
i m seeing that 2 numbers from 3 `mobile_numbers` are there in users table.
i m trying to show `mobile_numbers` present in users table i.e 2.
bt problem is that my code is showing 3 arrays .
2 with present row(as array).
And showing 3rd row as null which i dnt want
i only want `mobile_numbers` present in users table i.e 2

Comment: don't use img ..post your text code ..

Comment: First of all you need know about CI database and Query Builder ..

Comment: Have you heard about `CI Query Builder` ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz .... no  sir

Comment: to remove null from our array you can simple use "array_filter"

Comment: Have you attempted to find out why you are getting Nulls... that would be the first step.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw NO sir not yer

Comment: @JaspreetSingh have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822311/php-with-framework-of-codeigniter/44822836#44822836) ?

Comment: yes sir i have tried, but it aslo not works

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you:

```
    $this->db->select('user_id,name,mobile_number');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('sent_invitation','sent_invitation.mobile_number=users.mobile_number');
    $this->db->where('users.user_id',$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly you just want results which are matching with your users table - in this case you can try a simple join like this

However - since you use an old function like `mysql_query` it suggests you are sitting on an older PHP version too - so i'm not sure which CI Version you use -

```
public function invitation_result()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $user_id =$this->input->get("user_id");
    $query = $this->db
        ->select("*")
        ->from("sent_invitations AS si")
        ->join("users AS u","u.mobile_number = si.mobile_number")
        ->where("user_id", $user_id)
        ->get();

    $arrUsers = [];
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() AS $row)
        {
            $arrUsers[] = array("user_id" => $row->user_id, "name" => $row->name, "mobile_number" => $row->mobile_number);
        }
    }
    return $arrUsers;
}
```

ps: next time you should paste your code instead of uploading a picture - its pretty rude to simply ignore the basic rules...